# Chosing the right query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have to build a query that will create a table for a customer - 'Frank Spencer'(you'll see him in the Customers table below).

New table should hold the grand total of every product the customer has ever bought, leaving out those on orders that have not yet been shipped, with each product only appearing once in the new table.

My tables are as below.

[image]

[image]

Could you please advise me which of the ones below is the best?

a)  `with customer as (select * from customers where lower(CustomerName) = 'frank spencer'),customerorders as(select OrderId from orders o where o.CustomerId in(select CustomerId from customer) and OrderShipped = 'True') select sum(oi.QuantityOrdered) as TotalOrdered, s.ItemName into franksorders from orderitems oi join stock s on oi.StockItemId = s.StockItemId where OrderId in(select * from customerorders) group by ItemName order by ItemName`

b)       `with customer as (select * from customers where lower(CustomerName) = 'frank spencer') join customerorders as(select OrderId from orders o where o.CustomerId in(select CustomerId from customer) and OrderShipped = 'True') select total(oi.QuantityOrdered) as TotalOrdered, s.ItemName into new table franksorders using orderitems oi join stock s on oi.StockItemId = s.StockItemId where OrderId in(select * from customerorders) group by ItemName order by ItemName`

c)        `with customer (select * from customers where 'frank spencer' in (CustomerName)) with customerorders (select OrderId from orders o where o.CustomerId in(select CustomerId from customer) and OrderShipped = 'True') select sum(oi.QuantityOrdered) as TotalOrdered, s.ItemName create table franksorders using orderitems oi join stock s on oi.StockItemId = s.StockItemId where OrderId in(select * from customerorders) group by ItemName order by ItemName`

d)        `using customer with (select * from customers where CustomerName = 'frank spencer' and customerorders with(select OrderId from orders o where o.CustomerId in(select CustomerId from customer) then OrderShipped = 'True') select sum(oi.QuantityOrdered) as TotalOrdered, s.ItemName into franksorders from orderitems oi join stock s on oi.StockItemId = s.StockItemId where OrderId in(select * from customerorders) group by ItemName order by ItemName`

Comment: In your testing, which one returns the desired result in the shortest time?

Comment: You rly just copied some school task and wants the asnwer...

Comment: This looks awfully homework-ish.  But leaving that aside, what defines 'best'?  What have you actually tried?

Comment: I would suggest the whole concept is massively flawed. This is storing calculated information which is going to be nothing but painful in the long run. You will have to devise all sorts of code to keep this table up to date. This would be far better suited as a view instead of a persistent table.

Comment: E)  All of the above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B,C, and D have a USING in them which is not supported in SQL Server from what I can tell. USE is, but not USING. So the answer is A. Next time, you can use poorsql.com to format your code like so and it's easier to find errors.

```
WITH customer
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM customers
    WHERE lower(CustomerName) = 'frank spencer'
    )
    ,customerorders
AS (
    SELECT OrderId
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.CustomerId IN (
            SELECT CustomerId
            FROM customer
            )
        AND OrderShipped = 'True'
    )
SELECT sum(oi.QuantityOrdered) AS TotalOrdered
    ,s.ItemName
INTO franksorders
FROM orderitems oi
INNER JOIN stock s ON oi.StockItemId = s.StockItemId
WHERE OrderId IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM customerorders
        )
GROUP BY ItemName
ORDER BY ItemName
```